# Stopping a timer in java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

sorry for bothering again.

I'm having troubles with stopping a timer.
I tried doing a boolean to which, after one run, it would get a false value and then cancel the timer, but it didn't work out.

The timer is supposed to run once at a specific time. Using timer.cancel() it canceled before running the task.

I figured that I could add a couple of milliseconds to the date so that it would stop (along with the timer.cancel()), but it didn't work.

I'm letting you know the code:

```
public class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    private String name;

    public MyTimeTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String yearMonth = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM"));
        String day = "05";
        Date date = dateFormatter.parse(yearMonth + "-" + day + " 02:10:08PM");

        System.out.println(yearMonth);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new MyTimeTask("Patrick");
        timer.schedule(task, date);
        long expiremilis = 10l;
        Date expireDate = new Date(date.getTime() + expiremilis);
        timer.cancel();
}
```

This was one of the ways I tried to fix this, but I couldn't, nor do I know if adding milliseconds to the chosen date is appropriate at all to make it stop.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks